# Entering mathematical formulas in GIS SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I was wondering if it is possible to enter mathematical formulas in GIS SE. I was trying to enter formulas about map projections and found it necessary.

I looked around, and from this meta question:
[How can I write math formula in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-stack-overflow-question) , it seems latex is supported in some SE website but not SO.

What about GIS SE?

If not supported, I would like to request this feature be supported in GIS SE.